# dictionary indexing with numpy array

Tags: python

I have

```
dict = {0 : 'red', 1 : 'blue', 2 : 'green'}
label = np.ndarray([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2])
```

As I want to get value corresponding to key by using label, I called

```
dict[label]
```

But I got

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: don't use `dict` as variable name in python

Comment: you have to provide key 0, 1, or 2. Not the numpy array. You can iterate the numpy array and use the elements as key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not quite as easy as that, but there are simple alternatives.
you can either have your "dict" (you shouldn't use reserved names) as an array as well:

```
my_dict = np.array(['red', 'blue', 'green'])
label = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2])
my_dict[[label]]
```

or you can use a comprehension:

```
[dict[item] for item in label]
```

Comment: The second method works, but when I use the first method, I got TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: @alryosha make you sure copied it correctly

Comment: Ah okay it's my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean this?

```
    dict = {0 : 'red', 1 : 'blue', 2 : 'green'}
    label = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2])
    for l in label:
        print(dict[l])
```

The output from this is:
red
red
red
blue
blue
blue
green
green
green

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map`. You need to iterate over `label` and take the corresponding value from the dictionary.
Note:

1. Don't use `dict` as a variable name in python
2. I suppose you want to use `np.array()` not `np.ndarray`

```py
d = {0 : 'red', 1 : 'blue', 2 : 'green'}
label = np.array([0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2])
output = list(map(lambda x: d[x], label))
```

output

```
['red', 'red', 'red', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'green']
```